# Angularjs dropdown select value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have this dropdown

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="LoanDetailsVM.PaymentPeriodMonths">
           <option value="1">Monthly</option>
           <option value="3">Quarterly</option>
 </select>
```

The LoanDetailsVM.PaymentPeriodMonths can be either 1 or 3, but the proper option is not selected when I'm opening the page.

Is there anything else I need to add in order for the correct option to be selected?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `[(ngModel)]` instead of `ng-model` and `[ngValue]` instead of `value`:

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="LoanDetailsVM.PaymentPeriodMonths">
       <option [ngValue]="1">Monthly</option>
       <option [ngValue]="3">Quarterly</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right, I'll accept your answer in 8 minutes.

Comment: @Laziale You're welcome. And it is unclear whether you are asking about Angular 2 or AngularJS, those are two totally different things, please make sure that is clear in your future questions.

Comment: AngularJS only, not Angular2 ATM. Thx

Comment: @Laziale Well, I am not sure that this works then, I've never used AngularJS, only Angular 2. I wrote this answer assuming you are using Angular 2.